# How do i know if my URI can be converted to a byte array (android)?

Tags: android, http, uri, inputstream, mime

ok, I'm making an application which allows the user to select a spreadsheet for upload to a server. I upload the file by getting the URI, converting to inputstream and then to a byte array, which I send as the content body. I get the URI using the Android Intent

`Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);`

This is the code I use to get my byte array:

```
is = contentResolver.openInputStream(importedFileUri);
String responseBody = null;
    int len;
    int buffSize = 1024;
    byte[] buf;
    byte[] byteArray = null;
    try {
        if (is != null) {
            if (is instanceof ByteArrayInputStream) {
                buffSize = is.available();

                buf = new byte[buffSize];
                len = is.read(buf, 0, buffSize);
            } else {
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                buf = new byte[buffSize];
                while ((len = is.read(buf, 0, buffSize)) != -1) {
                    bos.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                byteArray = bos.toByteArray();

            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and finally

```
    ContentBody cbFile = new ByteArrayBody(byteArray, fileName);
    MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    mpEntity.addPart("uploadFile", cbFile);
    httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
```

for drive/cloud files, the byte array (and possibly the input stream itself) is null. How can I detect whether the user has selected a drive file and download that file so that I can convert it to a byte array?

I logged this data for a drive file URI:

> URI path: /document/acc=1;doc=2 /document/acc%3D1%3Bdoc%3D2
>
> URI Scheme: content
>
> resolved type (content) : application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet
>
> ext: null

and this for a local file:

> URI path: /document/549 /document/549
>
> URI Scheme content
>
> resolved type (content) : application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
>
> ext: xlsx

i got ext(ension) like so:

```
if (importedFileUri.getScheme().equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)) {
                    final MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
                    ext = mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(mActivity.getContentResolver().getType(importedFileUri));
                    System.out.println("resolved type (content) : "+ mActivity.getContentResolver().getType(importedFileUri));
                } else {
                    ext = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(new File(importedFileUri.getPath())).toString());
                    System.out.println("resolved type (other) : "+ Uri.fromFile(new File(importedFileUri.getPath())).toString());
                }
```

EDIT: the `InputStream` itself is null. So how do I Access a drive/cloud file?

Comment: OK, so I got some idea by using the `getAuthority()` method, but there is'nt a consistency there. a drive file would have something like `com.android.apps.drive.something`, but a local file might be `com.android.externalstorage.something` or `com.android.providers.downloads.somehting`. Is this clear cut? will this vary with OEMs and FileManagers? anyone know anything?